# Why doesn't my XML Parser open the connection?

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, xml-parsing

I'm applying a XML Parser to consume a XML file on this URL: http://www.emmebistudio.com/markers.xml to keep marker datas for a map into an android app. This is my code that should parse it, but with the eclipse debugger I've seen that it return connected = false at the second line, so, where am I wrong?

```
try{
    URL url = new URL("http://www.emmebistudio.com/markers.xml");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    //Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

    NodeList markers = doc.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    for (int i = 0; i < markers.getLength(); i++) {
        Element item = (Element) markers.item(i);
        String name = item.getAttribute("name");
        String address = item.getAttribute("address");
        String stringLat = item.getAttribute("lat");
        String stringLong = item.getAttribute("long");
        String icon = item.getAttribute("icon"); //assigned variable for the XML icon attribute
        Double lat = Double.valueOf(stringLat);
        Double lon = Double.valueOf(stringLong);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                .title(name)
                .snippet(address));

    }


}catch (Exception e){
    // If I can't connect to the file I only see the map with my position
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: are you running that snippet on the UI Thread?

Comment: yes it's only for a try.. if it will run smoothly I'll do a java class

Comment: That's actually the problem. Probably you are getting the NetworOnMainThreadException, but since you are not printing the stacktrace it is hard to say exactly what's going on

Comment: take it off the UI thread. Use the debugger. Spot the exception.

Comment: Does your manifest include permission to use internet?

Comment: erad Yes my manifest include that permission. @blackbelt and RichieHH this is what the stacktrace print: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed some Kb of memory and it returns how much ms after going in pause. What does it mean?

Comment: After you opened the connection, better do `conn.connect()` and `conn.getInputStream()` instead of `url.openStream()`.

Comment: @JoopEggen nothing to do, the problem is some lines above. Take a look on this screen: http://i277.photobucket.com/albums/kk71/ErikaSparrow/Immagine.png

it said connected = false :/

Comment: `openConnection` does _not_ connect. You can do settings like `setDoOutput(true);` and _then_ call `connect();`. (Misleading API)

Comment: @JoopEggen but setDoOutput(true) isn't for "POST" requests? In this case I have to do a "GET" request. I have to retrieve datas from the xml on that URL...

Comment: `setDoOutput` was just an example; but could be used for headers, like faking being a browser with a User-Agent header, Keep-Alive, accepting compressed data etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add Internet Access.

Add the INTERNET permission to your manifest file.

You have to add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml